# Spring Batch 3.0 Best way to pass 250+ String as jobParameter

Tags: spring, spring-batch

My rest controller below receives a List of ids and sends a json string of the List as a jobParameter to a Spring Batch Job.

```
@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
Job job;

RequestMapping(value="/startjob", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<EventReports> addReportIds(@RequestBody List<Integer> reportIds) throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    try {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
            .addString("eventType", "Event Reports")
            .addString("reportIdsJson", reportIds.toString())
            .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Completed event reports batch job");
    return null;
}
```

My Spring Batch reader looks like

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class Reader implements ItemReader<String> {

    private String[] messages = {"Hello World!", "Welcome to Spring Batch!"};

    @Value("#{jobParameters['time']}")
    private Long time;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['eventType']}")
    private String eventType;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['reportIdsJson']}")
    private String reportIdsJson;

    private int count=0;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public String read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        System.out.println("Time: " + time);
        System.out.println("Type: " + eventType);
        System.out.println("JSON: " + reportIdsJson);

        if(count < messages.length){
            return messages[count++];
        }else{
            count=0;
        }
```

The problem I'm running into is - the JSON string I'm passing as a jobParameter can be quite large, and I am definitely over the 250 character limit.  When the JSON string I'm passing as a jobParameter to my Reader is larger than 250 characters, I get an error that looks like this

```
Started event reports batch job
2017-05-01 10:50:03.662  INFO 8724 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean def
initions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
2017-05-01 10:50:03.788  INFO 8724 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : SQLErrorCodes loaded
: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
2017-05-01 10:50:04.296  INFO 8724 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] c.u.r.s.RailAgentCollectorServiceImpl    : PreparedStatementCal
lback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, KEY_NAME, TYPE_CD, STRING_VAL, DATE_VAL, LONG_VAL,
DOUBLE_VAL, IDENTIFYING) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; String or binary data would be truncated.; nested exception i
s com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.
Completed event reports batch job
```

I have looked at various approaches to this problem.  The one that I'm trying right now is - instead of passing the very large JSON string as a jobParameter to Spring Batch, save it to a temp database table as a String - then use the other jobParameters passed to Spring Batch to query my temp database table for the very large JSON string.  So, before even starting my Spring Batch job, I have to save the JSON string to my temp db table.  This solution does not seem 'clean' to me - ideally I'd just like to pass my large JSON string to my batch job and immediately start my processing.  Instead I have to first save the very large JSON string to the temp db before starting my Spring Batch job - so this part of the processing exists outside of Spring Batch.  So my code in this case looks like

```
//save list of Integers JSON to temp db table here
 try {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
            .addString("eventType", "Event Reports")
            .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Completed event reports batch job");
    return null;
}
```

for my rest controller, and for my Reader

```
@Override
public String read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    System.out.println("Time: " + time);
    System.out.println("Type: " + eventType);

    //use above 2 job parameters to query temp db table for large JSON string
    //pass large JSON string to my Spring Batch Processor
}
```

Is there a better way to design this?  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Write JSON to a file and use an item reader to retrieve the ids?

Comment: Why not just up the limit?  If it's for the Spring Batch tables, I'm pretty sure there is nothing in code that imposes that limit.  It's just a sensible default.

Comment: Is it wise to keep the job parameters in a temp db table? Because then you're gonna lose the actual parameters later on which might be a pain for maintenance and general troubleshooting?

Comment: Please tell us how are you planning to execute the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken @MichaelMinella 's advice - and I've upped the 250 varchar limit for batch job execution parameters.  The way I did it was

- I edited the schema-sqlserver.sql script that I was initializing spring.batch.schema with like

  CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS  (
      JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL ,
      TYPE_CD VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL ,
      KEY_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
      STRING_VAL VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
      DATE_VAL DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
      LONG_VAL BIGINT NULL,
      DOUBLE_VAL DOUBLE PRECISION NULL,
      IDENTIFYING CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
      constraint JOB_EXEC_PARAMS_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
      references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
  ) ;

Then I point to the hand edited schema-sqlserver.sql file in application.properties

```
spring.batch.schema=classpath:BOOT-INF/classes/sql/schema-sqlserver.sql
```

I'm now able to pass 250+ character Strings as jobParameters to my Spring Batch job.